# How can I use Google Contacts in Gnome Contacts?

Tags: google, contacts

1. I open Gnome Contacts (left)
2. I click on `Online Accounts`
3. I added my Google Account (right)
4. I restart Gnome Contacts

**Result:**

It still doesn't show my Google Contacts.

**Question:**

How can I use Google Contacts with Gnome Contacts?

[image: Gnome Contact]

Comment: I had to restart my system for the Google Account to appear in the selection menu.